# Exporting / Converting / Generating python data to Perl hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, perl

my first post in here :)

I have written an python script that does some quite some work and at the end the script should write some of its output to a perlmodule.
This perlmodule is a part of a Testing-Framework written in Perl but not modifiable (I can't use strict JSON for this type of data).
My current solution isn't optimal (as I think) and I want to optimize the code. I don't that much about perl, I only started to use it a bit.

My current solution is to compose a "String" inside python that has the correct syntax of the Perl Hash to be added to a perlmodule file (This file contains a lot of Hashes and functions), basically I want to append to this perlmodule file from within python.

```py
# Example data generated from the py script
name_of_this_hash = "some_perl_hash_name"
name_of_folder = "some_testfolder"
name_of_file = "some_testfile"
description = "some_perl_description"

folder_and_name = name_of_folder + "/" + name_of_file

# Actual Export / Conversion to Perl Hash
string = "\n \
\n \
\n" + name_of_this_hash + " => \
\n{ \
\n    _desc => '" + description +  "', \
\n    params => { message => '', additional_val => 0 }, \
\n    consts => { enabled => 'net,mem', \
\n        reports => 'net,mem', \
\n    }, \
\n    files => { \
\n        storage_loc_1 => '" + folder_and_name + ".txt', \
\n    }, \
\n    debDesc => $debugDesc, mainvalues => $mainvalDesc, \
\n},"

# Dummy Print, string would be appended to perlmodule
print(string)
```

The Python Code will produce the following Perl Hash:

```perl
some_perl_hash_name =>                                                                                                                                                                  
{                                                                                                                                                                                       
    _desc => 'some_perl_description',                                                                                                                                                   
    params => { message => '', additional_val => 0 },                                                                                                                                   
    consts => { enabled => 'net,mem',                                                                                                                                                   
        reports => 'net,mem',                                                                                                                                                           
    },                                                                                                                                                                                  
    files => {                                                                                                                                                                          
        storage_loc_1 => 'some_testfolder/some_testfile.txt',                                                                                                                       
    },                                                                                                                                                                                  
    debDesc => $debugDesc, mainvalues => $mainvalDesc,                                                                                                                                  
},
```

This hash is surrounded by the following:

```
our $TESTS =
{
# Generated Hashes go here
}
# Some functions that define what the test does
```

The framework in other places clone this "TESTS" and executes the functions based on the values that have been set (generated). But any further is probably irrelevant.

As you can see, I'm writing Strings with the Perl Hash syntax and adding some variables through python with combining strings. I would like to be able to have it "cleaner" and not to use Strings to compose that Hash for Perl.
The output `string` would be what I append to the Perlmodule.

How can I create this Perl Hash directly in python without the usage of creating strings with the correct syntax, etc. to be inserted to the perlmodule file?

Thanks for some advice,
Manuel

EDIT: Changed String composing, as stated in first comment :)
EDIT2: I now have understood that what I'm looking for is called "Hash" or "Hash Table" (instead of "Object") in Perl (Unstructured Key-Value), comparable with the "dict" in python - I have Improved my question to be more clear / specific
EDIT3: Added sample output from generated python code

Comment: Well, your output looks very much like JSON (but not complaint) if you could make it complaint JSON then store it as a file. In perl code read file into a variable and decode the variable  to restore the object. Please check if following [python code](https://www.onlinegdb.com/SJswRRtDU) is more acceptable than what you have provided (_I got tears in my eyes seeing how you manipulate the string_).

Comment: May be you will prefer string manipulation of following form [python code](https://onlinegdb.com/HkA-WycDI)

Comment: Yes, I know the string manipulations are horrible - I took them from the previous maintainer of the script (I will change this) - not really the topic I was asking about tho :). I'm not able to change anything within the Perl framework because this is being used in production this way. The step through JSON I would prefer too, but simply not possible. Are there other options to write this Perl Object directly from within python?

Comment: If you shed some light how you use this code in perl code then it would be helpful. At this moment you could just give a content of the file (written by python) and asked how to use it in perl. Otherwise so far it does not make much sense as you refer to something abstract.

Comment: This Perl object is being used to specify a testcase that the whole framework will read from the perlmodule. This part that i try to construct are just the parameters / inputs on what test to be executed / what output it gives specifically, in the last part of the whole perlmodule there are functions that define what this test actually does. I don't know that much about Perl (is this even called "object"?) Basically this part does the same as JSON but instead of it being seperate, the framework is implemented to get this input data from the perlmodule itself (the part I'm trying to compose).

Comment: I have updated the Question to be more precise about what i was calling "Perl object". I have learnd that this type of data is called "Hash" in Perl.

Comment: Please show an example of the generated Perl module